# Git command to discard a modified or untracked file

Tags: git

I would love to be able to run a command that discards the changes to one particular file, whether it's untracked or modified.

Right now I run `git status` and it gives me something like this:

```
$ git st
On branch master
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

        modified:   hello1.txt

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

        hello2.txt
```

To discard `hello1.txt`, I should run

```
git checkout -- hello1.txt
```

To discard `hello2.txt`, I could run something like

```
git clean -f -- hello2.txt
```

or, since `git status` might show me a whole directory that's untracked, I could run

```
git clean -fd -- directory
```

And sometimes I don't know whether it's modified or untracked right away; for instance, I could run `git checkout developmentbranch` and see

```
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout:
        hello3.txt
Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can switch branches.
Aborting
```

Is it modified or untracked? I have to run `git status`, find the problematic file in the output, determine the correct command to run to discard it, and run it. 3 more steps than I'd like to take.

Is there a command I can run to do either one? I just want to get rid of the changes -- I don't really care whether git already knows about them or not, I just want those particular changes gone.

EDIT:

Note that I don't want to get rid of everything, just one particular file. Maybe when I try `git checkout`, git only complains about one file -- then I just want to get rid of that one file, not nuke all of my changes.

Comment: Have you tried to add that file to the git ignore or the assume unchanged list?

Comment: It's not always the same file -- I'll just often be experimenting with something, and then want to change branches. I don't care enough about the changes to commit or stash them separately, but I might as well keep them around as long as they're not in the way. So if one conflicts, sure, I'll get rid of it. But I don't want it always ignored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a way. Maybe you can create a shortcut for this:

```
git checkout --quiet -- $file || git clean --quiet -fd -- $file
```

To list the untracked or modified files you can use `git ls-files`.

Comment: I tried to go down this route as well, but couldn't get it to work as I wanted. Looks like this does what I need. Except `--quiet` doesn't prevent git from telling me `error: pathspec 'hello.txt' did not match any file(s) known to git.` Do you know of any way to get rid of this warning?

Comment: Yes, add '2> /dev/null' at the end of the command. Send an email to the Git mailing list (git@vger.kernel.org), that's a bug.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `git reset`:

```
git reset <file>
```

Remove the specified file from the staging area, but leave the working directory unchanged. This unstages a file without overwriting any changes.

```
git reset
```

Reset the staging area to match the most recent commit, but leave the working directory unchanged. This unstages all files without overwriting any changes, giving you the opportunity to re-build the staged snapshot from scratch.

```
git reset --hard
```

Reset the staging area and the working directory to match the most recent commit. In addition to unstaging changes, the `--hard` flag tells Git to overwrite all changes in the working directory, too. Put another way: this obliterates all uncommitted changes, so make sure you really want to throw away your local developments before using it.

https://es.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/undoing-changes/git-reset

Comment: `git reset` is helpful, but in this case I don't want to discard _all_ changes, just one particular change. I don't want to get rid of everything (`git reset --hard; git clean -fd`), I just want to revert the changes to one file.

Comment: So git reset <file> won't do the trick for you because you still have to know which file, right?

Comment: Well, I already know what file I want to discard, but `git reset <file>` won't do the trick because it doesn't change my working directory, and the working directory is what I want to change. Since you can't use `git reset --hard` with a file path, I can't get rid of just the one particular file. And anyway, `git reset --hard` doesn't do anything to untracked files, so it doesn't help me any more than `git checkout -- <file>`.